# Synthesis of a lactone

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm solving some synthesis problems for practice and I came across this one:

[image]

I thought of going for compound A to B(aldehyde) with this procedure:

1. $\ce{t-BuOK}$
2. $\ce{BH3,THF,NaOH,H2O2}$
3. $\ce{PCC,CH2Cl2}$

For the second path, in order to get to a lactone, I don't know what to do. I see that the carbonyl bond is moved to another carbon. I've learnt a way, in order to get an ester, is to add an alcohol $\ce{ROH}$ to an acyl chloride. But I'm so confused.

Comment: What do three arrows signify? Three synthetic steps, or just a very fast transition?:)

Comment: You have added a 4 carbon unit to your aldehyde. How many steps are you contemplating?

Comment: @andselisk I really don't know, the exercise just asks to write the reagents which will lead to the wanted compounds.

Comment: @Waylander Ι don't know where to start, im really confused. The part that confuses me the most, is that there are 4 carbon atoms added, but they are in a ring and i wonder if it is an intramolecular type of thing or not

Comment: @chemistryluvv Would it be possible  for you to attach the image of the original problem, or literally quote it? Does the currently shown reaction scheme also appear like this in the original?

Comment: @andselisk Im so sorry, i can't post it because it comes out very blurry. The compounds are shown exactly the same and the exercise says: ''Starting from compound A, predict the reagents required for the synthesis of the other two''.

Comment: Consider also https://old.reddit.com/r/chemhelp/comments/gvuz0l/synthesis_of_a_lactone/ and https://old.reddit.com/r/chemhelp/comments/h093mj/synthesis_of_this_ester/ for some other guidance

Comment: It's a bit hard to know what to suggest for your lactone without knowing how much you know. Personally, I would try 1-(trimethylsiloxy)-1,3-butadiene and attempt a [4+2] cycloaddition, but that's weird to suggest if you haven't learned about that class of reactions yet. Also, we generally try to avoid PCC unless other methods aren't working. Chromium waste is not good for the environment. These days one might attempt something like a Swern oxidation.

Comment: Add a 5-carbon unit via the Grignard reagent of 5-bromo-1-pentene to the aldehyde. Ozonolysis of the double bond to a hydroxy aldehyde that will likely form the hemiacetal. Oxidize with PCC

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to make the lactone:

1. To your aldehyde in dry THF at 0 °C, add the commercially available 3-butenylmagnesium bromide. Work up and collect the resulting secondary alcohol.
2. React the alcohol with dihydropyran in dry $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ to form the THP ether.
3. React this THP ether with $\ce{BH3.THF}$ as you did before, but do an oxidative work up with PDC to get the carboxylic acid according to Brown et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00049a024)], or do the basic peroxide as before to get the aldehyde, then oxidise that.
4. Treat the product acid with PTSA in MeOH to remove the pyran ether, the lactone will form spontaneously.

Your choice of alcohol protecting group will be driven by the oxidation conditions you use for the borane. THPO is known to be stable to PDC/$\ce{CrO3}$ in pyridine.

#### Reference

1. Brown, H. C.; Kulkarni, S. V.; Khanna, V. V.; Patil, V. D.; Racherla, U. S. Organoboranes for Synthesis. 14. Convenient Procedures for the Direct Oxidation of Organoboranes from Terminal Alkenes to Carboxylic Acids. *J. Org. Chem.* **1992**, 57 (23), 6173–6177. DOI: [10.1021/jo00049a024](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00049a024).